# Animating UITextView width with overflow

Tags: ios, uitextview, uiviewanimation

I have a `UITextView` containing some text that fills the whole width without overflowing.

I'm reducing the width of the `UITextView` by changing its frame in a block animation, such that the decreased width causes the text to overflow and the end to be replaced with an `ellipsis` ('...').

Currently, the text does not respond smoothly to the changing width. It jumps from the full width case to the truncated '...' case without anything in between, and the same when animating back to the full width.

Is it possible to force the text to change and the `ellipsis` to be introduced/removed smoothly as the frame animates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the answer here: [UITextView animating change of frame does not animate text reallocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402985/uitextview-animating-change-of-frame-does-not-animate-text-reallocation)

*The text in textviews doesn't always act as expected. For this you'll have to set up a NSTimer and set the frame size on every tick.
Do something like*:

```
textview.frame = CGRectMake (textview.frame.origin.x, textview.frame.origin.y,   textview.frame.size.width-1, textview.frame.size.height-1);
```

*Then when it's done I would completely remove the textview from superview and set it to nil, and then init a new one. The reason for this is that when changes the frames of textviews for some reason padding is added around the text's box. You won't notice it unless you change the frame a probably at least 100 times.*

```
[textview removeFromSuperview];
textview = nil;
textview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
textview.text = yourTextString;
//You will also have to set whatever non default properties you want, such as text or background color
[view addSubview:textview];
```